# Python dimension mismatch for multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimension

I have a few variables listed below. How come I receive the error message at the bottom when I try to run this block of code? `Ind_var[i,:]` should be of shape (1,2) so by matrix multiplication (1,2) * (2,2) is (1,2)? Sorry I'm new to python.

```
import numpy as np

spread_len = 10
n_param = 2
Q = np.zeros((spread_len,1))
ind_var = np.zeros((spread_len,2))
R = np.zeros((n_param,n_param))
Ve = 0.001

for i in range(spread_len):
     Q[i]=ind_var[i,:]*R*ind_var[i,:]+Ve
```

Error message:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into
>   shape (1)

Comment: You might be confusing `*` with the matrix-multiplication in MATLAB, as opposed to in NumPy that goes as elementwise multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transpose the second ind_var[i,:] to get a (2,1) shape, otherwise you're spanning a new (2,2) matrix which doesn't fit into Q[i] which is shape (1).

Also R and ind_var need to be matrices, not arrays, for matrix math:

```
import numpy as np

spread_len = 10
n_param = 2
Q = np.zeros((spread_len,1))
ind_var = np.asmatrix(np.zeros((spread_len,2)))
R = np.asmatrix(np.zeros((n_param,n_param)))
Ve = 0.001

for i in range(spread_len):
    Q[i]=ind_var[i,:]*R*ind_var[i,:].T+Ve
```

Maybe not a beautiful solution, but you can go from here and use matlib to create matrices.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib as ml

spread_len = 10
n_param = 2
Q = np.zeros((spread_len,1))
ind_var = ml.zeros((spread_len,2))
R = ml.zeros((n_param,n_param))
Ve = 0.001

for i in range(spread_len):
    Q[i]=ind_var[i,:]*R*ind_var[i,:].T+Ve
```

Comment: So I  tried `np.transpose` the second `ind_var[i,:]`, as `Q[i] = ind_var[i,:]*R*np.transpose(ind_var[i,:])+Ve` but I still get the same error message **ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (1)**

Comment: You can use `np.matrix` directly, without importing the `ml` module.

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

```
In [970]: ind_var.shape
Out[970]: (10, 2)

In [971]: R.shape
Out[971]: (2, 2)

In [972]: ind_var[0,:]*R*ind_var[0,:]+Ve
Out[972]: 
array([[ 0.001,  0.001],
       [ 0.001,  0.001]])
```

For arrays, the `*` multiplication is element by element, like MATLAB `.*`.  So the result is shape of `R`, and the wrong size to put in a cell of `Q`.

There is an array matrix multiplication, `np.dot`:

```
In [973]: np.dot(ind_var[0,:], np.dot(R, ind_var[0,:]))+Ve
Out[973]: 0.001
```

There is an array subclass, `np.matrix` that is constrained to be 2d (like old MATLAB) and uses `*` for matrix product

```
In [981]: Rm=np.matrix(R)  
In [982]: ind_m=np.matrix(ind_var)
In [983]: ind_m[0,:]*R*ind_m[0,:].T+Ve
Out[983]: matrix([[ 0.001]])
```

`np.einsum` is a generalization of `np.dot` that can perform all calculations in one step

```
In [985]: np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i', ind_var, R, ind_var)+Ve
Out[985]: 
array([ 0.001,  0.001,  0.001,  0.001,  0.001,  0.001,  0.001,  0.001,
        0.001,  0.001])
```

`R` and `ind_var` values are all 0 in this example, so the results aren't diagnositic - except for shape.

I was going to suggest the new `matmul` operator, `@` but `ind_var@R@ind_var.T` produces a 10x10 array, which is not what we want.  The iterative `ind_var[0,:]@R@ind_var[0,:]` is ok.

(I really should test things with nontrivial values).